# Add a css class to <%= @quest.text %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, erb

Should be a relatively simple question -- I'm trying to add a css class ("quiz-question") to this line:

```
<%= @question.text  %>
```

If I add it directly after

```
<%= @question.text :class => "quiz-question" %>
```

I get an argument error saying wrong number of arguments (1 of 0), and I've tried separating with a comma or putting the class inside curly brackets. What's the correct way to include here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're trying to pass an argument to a displayed item.
`@question.text` isn't a tag, a block, a helper, etc. It's only text. And thus, you can't give it a class.

Why don't you do `<span class="quizz-question"><%= @question.text %></span>`?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the response. Had tried that with a div before and it hadn't worked for some reason, but this works great.